# Swapping the contents of 2 drives with Windows Explorer without needing to copy-and-delete?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, windows-explorer, windows-11, storage

I have local 2 drives, neither of them my Windows boot drive:

- A 2TB HDD, drive letter `E:`. Contains about 300GB of data.
- A 1TB SSD, drive letter `F:`. Contains about 4GB of data.

I want to swap the contents of these drives. I can do this with Windows Explorer, but that would create a copy of the data in the destination drive, leaving me to need to delete the original files from the source drive.

Is there a way to just **move** the files between drives without needing to copy the files, then deleting the original?

Comment: Try the Windows Command MV:    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/move

Comment: given that you move between drives, the data itself will move by making a copy and then deleting the original. It will be slow regardless. But you can just make a selection, right-mouse-click, cut, destination, right-mouse-click, paste, and it will move the data.

Comment: Try Robocopy, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy , which has many options and is more efficient and *robust*  at moving data. BTW, if the files and folders have different  names, then this is simple... but if there is *overlap* of some, moving from A to B would overwrite those files, and then those in B could not be moved to A. You'd need a *third* drive (or move into subfolders).

Comment: Moving files between filesystems is always copying followed by deleting. Without deleting it would be just copying. Are you asking "how can I do this, so deleting happens *automatically*?"?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to just move the files between drives without needing to copy the files, then deleting the original?

This does not make sense.
"Deleting the orginal" suggests that you made a copy, something you excluded.

"Swapping the contents" suggests that the F-drive uses a maximum of 300 GB.
You could swap the drive labels.